# Online Gemoro Shiurim

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, internet, adult-learning

Are there any websites where I can listen/download a Gemara shiur in English with rishonim, acharonim at a relatively high level?

I'm not looking for daf yomi bekiyus shiurim but rather a deeper more iyundik one and preferably one with marei mekomos to help prepare for the shiur.

Comment: Rabbi Eli Mansour has some iyun versions for his Daf Yomi: http://www.dailygemara.com/Default.asp?MasechetID=1

Answer (score 2):

I quite like the gemara shiurim at Rav Nissan Kaplan's [Daf Yomi Review](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/). Many of them also include *mar'ei mekomos* as a .gif file - such as [these ones](http://ravkaplan.dafyomireview.com/cd.php?cdall=talmud/5772-Gittin), from the first and fourth perakim of Gittin. I would consider them to be reasonably high level (for me, certainly) - at least insofar as they look *be'iyyun* at a variety of different Rishonim.

Comment: Looks good. Shame he doesn't have shiurim on the 8th perek bava basra.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably thousands of shiurim on Gemara, as many 'maggidei shiur' will upload their lectures on the internet. There are two general ways to find them:

- by looking for a particular yeshiva or teacher, such as the audio library of [Yeshivas Ohr Reuvain](http://www.ohrreuven.com/audio_library.php), [Rav Yitzchok Lichtenstein](http://www.kbaforshay.com/Rabbi%20Lichtenstein%20Mp3%20B.htm) (both of those are rabbis in Monsey) or [Yeshiva Toras Moshe](http://www.nermichoel.org/shiurim.php), for example.
- if you don't know (or care) about the particular lecturer or yeshiva, there are two free online databases of shiurim, both of which are huge and excellent: http://kolhalashon.com (which has thousands of excellent shiurim from many lecturers, including world-renown roshei yeshiva) and http://yutorah.com (with shiurim from lecturers who are associated with Yeshiva University, and many which come with PDFs of 'mareh mekomos')