# Looking for the right daf yomi shiur

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, internet, adult-learning, daf-yomi

I'm looking for the right daf yomi shiur that I can download online. I know there's a lot to choose from, so hopefully my criteria are specific enough to lead you in the right direction. I'm looking for something where:

- The objective is for each listener to do chazara from the knowledge shared in the shiur. An emphasis on what uncommon words mean and a clear, very phsat explanation of the shakle v'taria. I'm **not** looking for a Rabbi who gives explanations "outside" of the text, or is discussion heavy.
- No commentaries. The purpose is to cover ground. The pshat given should be in light of what the commentaries say, but I don't want the machlokes between Rashi and Tosefos to be explained - just give me the one that makes the most sense, or just give me either.
- about an hour long, covers a whole daf

Just for context, I'm deeply engaged with [Rabbi Pogrow's](http://mastertorah.org) bekius mishna shiur - it's a perfect example of these requirements! I tried his gemara shiur and found it too slow and a little more in depth than I want. I have a background in gemara learning, so I'm not looking for a shiur that teaches you skills to learn or keywords.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I wish you much success with your quest. I don't understand "The objective is for each listener to learn how to read the daf themselves. An emphasis on what uncommon words mean and a clear, very phsat explanation of the shakle v'taria". That first sentence makes it sound like you want the _shiur_ to reach you how to study _G'mara_ on your own (which is, by the way, an unusual aim for a _shiur_ in _daf yomi_ afaik), but then it would stress explanation of *common* words, wouldn't it? — because those are the ones you'll need to know as you move on to new _G'mara_.

Comment: "clear, very phsat explanation of the shakle v'taria" - The tone of your question is somewhat self-contradictory. You are seeking a "simple" explanation of difficult words, yet, for many MY readers, you are using terms in your own question that need explanation! You should consider translating these words. I apologize if I appear persnickety.

Comment: Related: [Online Gemoro Shiurim](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53464/online-gemoro-shiurim)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the clarifying questions. I have a background in learning and am familiar with keywords and learning skills, so I'm not looking for a rabbi to explain those. I'm also **not** looking for a rabbi to use the gemara as a springboard for his own explanations. Rather, I want a rabbi who understands that his explanation will be used for a lot of chazara and therefore needs to be clear. I'll update my question with this added context and clarification.

Comment: If you expect no commentaries, no discussion off the page, etc, why should it take an hour?